# uiview not drawing when constrained programmatically

Tags: swift, view, uiview, subclass, nslayoutconstraint

My code is trying to call a class which controlls all the drawing properties and nothing is showing up on the uiview. It's like the class is not being called but I know its being called. I don't know what to do. It is important that canvas covers a specific area and not the entire view thats why I programmed constraint it.

```
var canvas = Canvas()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    canvas.backgroundColor = .black
    setupLayout()
    canvas.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(canvas)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
          canvas.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :150),
          canvas.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : 0),
          canvas.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
          canvas.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
    ])
}


class Canvas: UIView {

// public function
func undo() {
    _ = lines.popLast()
    setNeedsDisplay()
}

func clear() {
    lines.removeAll()
    setNeedsDisplay()
}

fileprivate var lines = [[CGPoint]]()

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    context.setLineWidth(5)
    context.setLineCap(.butt)

    lines.forEach { (line) in
        for (i, p) in line.enumerated() {
            if i == 0 {
                context.move(to: p)
            } else {
                context.addLine(to: p)
            }
        }
    }

    context.strokePath()
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    lines.append([CGPoint]())
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: nil) else { return }
    guard var lastLine = lines.popLast() else { return }
    lastLine.append(point)
    lines.append(lastLine)
    setNeedsDisplay()
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the below line

```
guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: nil) else { return }
```

to this

```
guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
```

The points stored in **lines** array are corresponding to the superview to which your **CanvasView** was attached to. You need to store the points corresponding to **CanvasView**. That's exactly what the **self** parameter does in place of **nil** above.